# Creating a repository using vs code in bitbucket

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, bitbucket

I wanted to create a repository in bitbucket for an existing spring boot application.
Usually I'll create a repository in bitbucket and clone it into local. Then start developing app from this location. So committing never was a problem. But now I've already created an app in local. I don't want to create a repo in bit bucket clone it in local. Then copy the content of the app to that location. So is there any way using vs code(since I've connected altassian bitbuket to it) to create a repo in bitbucket and commit the code. Also I already have git installed.
Thanks.

Comment: Create an empty repo on bitbucket (no readme, no gitignore, etc), then add the repo URL as a remote, then push the branches you want.

Comment: The reason I didn't answer is because I believe someone else has asked a question just like this. I just can't find it